# How to logrotate Docker containers with journald log-driver

Tags: docker, logging, systemd

I would like to achieve log rotation for Docker containers, but also preserve logs on Docker container recreate (docker compose up --force-recreate). [Local driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/local/) seems perfect (it allows custom file size, number of rotations and optional compression of old rotations), but logs get lost when Docker container gets recreated.

[Jurnald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/) seems to be the answer, but I can't find a way to have control over log rotations of individual Docker containers. Docker container's logs are logged along of Docker daemon (journalctl -u docker.service), but can be filtered like this (journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=webserver).

Any clue would be greatly appreciated (eg. syslog hack to filter by container name and log it separately, but native journald filtering would be probably the proper solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I understand, that a bot wrote this. But, what specifically can I do about "specific problem" and "enough detail"? I think that both are emphasized enough...